# Save ML.NET IDataView to a database table without POCO

Tags: c#, ml.net

I have a transformed `IDataView` with prediction (`Score`) column, input columns and one-hot encoded columns. I want to save only prediction and input values to a database table.

Usually, one could convert `IDataView` to `IEnumerable` and write that to a table:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> predictionsEnumerable =
    mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<SomeType>(predictions, reuseRowObject: true);
```

The problem is that I don't have a `SomeType` defined, and `dynamic` is not supported in this case, because the method reads public properties from a [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object).

Is it possible to somehow insert these values to a table just by using [DataViewSchema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.dataviewschema?view=ml-dotnet)?